# Auto-generated posts not showing in backend (but being counted!)

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-insert-post, post-status

I have a custom post type with a custom backend page.

I'm creating posts of that type using this code:

```
$postarr = array(

        "post_type" => "product_settings",
        "post_status" => "published",
        "post_title" => "$ean $name",
        "post_content" => "$ean $name", // to satisfy WP requirement
        "meta_input" => array("ean" => $ean)
    );

    $id = wp_insert_post($postarr);

    if (!$id)
        echo "ERR: unable to create post for product $name";
    else
        update_field("ean", $ean, $id); // THis is an ACF custom field
```

However, on the backend page, the posts I auto-generate are being *counted*, but there's no way to make them show up in the list! The only one that's showing is one I created manually in the backend.

[image]

I tried all the display options, searching for a string I know is in those auto-generated posts... nothing.

What am I overlooking while generating those posts?

This is the code for the custom post type, should be fairly straightforward:

```
    register_post_type( 'product_settings',

        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Produkte' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Produkt' ),
                'add_new_item' => __('Neues Produkt')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product_settings'),
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'product_settings' ),
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,

        )
    );
```

Comment: That's incredibly strange. Are you sure there is nothing hooked to filters that would interfere while auto-generating the posts?

Comment: @JackJohansson pretty sure! It's a vanilla WP install with a custom post type and a custom taxonomy, nothing more.

Comment: @JackJohansson argh, I looked into the database and it turns out it was a simple typo! See below.

Answer (score 2):

Ugggggggh.

```
"post_status" => "published",
```

is incorrect. It should be

```
 "post_status" => "publish",
```

This apparently puts posts into a state of limbo in which they're not visible in the list (but still counted for some reason).

Comment: been there ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs `post_title` & `post_content` are required, Wordpress will not generate an empty published post.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: I added some content in `post_content`, but the result is the same: the post count rises every time I run the post-auto-generator script, but no posts become visible. Weird! Updating the question to reflect the addition.

Comment: Yes quite strange, have you used pre_get_posts in your theme? Maybe you forgot to test if (! is_admin())?

Comment: nope, definitely not! It's a vanilla WP install with this on top